# Probability of matching items in a subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say there are 12 balls, numbered 1-12, {1,2....12}. Exactly 5 balls are red, but you don't know the numbers. You are asked to guess the order of the numbers that will be drawn one by one without replacement.

What is the probability that you guess at least two of the red balls correctly?

An example for clarification: your guess is {1,2,4...}
and the third ball drawn has the number 4 and is red, that would be the case  of you guessing at least 1 red correctly.

My thoughts:

It is without replacement, so there are 12! ways one could order the numbers.
To account for undercounting, would use combinatorics. Im thinking that:

Sum((5C2)*(7CX))/12!, where the sum goes from 0-7. Sorry about not formatting correctly, this is my first question, and I don't understand it yet.

Comment: What’s your thoughts first?

Comment: This isn't clear at all.  What does it mean to be told each flavor before the testing?  How does the flavor relate to the place that makes the pizza?  Is the person informed as to the results of each guess as they go?  As stated, it's simply not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I realise upon re-reading that the English is horrendous.   But anyway, the person is only informed about the results after guessing them all. There is no relation between the flavour and the place that makes the pizza, let's say flavour is synonymous with the pizza's name. To be told the flavour before testing is to be told all 12 names before testing.

Comment: Obviously, there are 12! ways that one can randomly assign the names. Assuming the order of the pizzas is random, my first thoughts were to use combinatorics to count the number of ways one could guess 2 right, then evaluate using the naive definition of probability.

Comment: I still have no idea what the question is.  I suggest deleting the references to pizza entirely as they add nothing at all.  I think, but am not sure, that you just have $12$ balls numbered $\{1, \cdots, 12\}$ in a bag of which exactly $5$ are red (but you don't know which numbers).  At the start, you guess the order of the numbers that will be drawn one by one without replacement and you ask for the probability that at least two of the ones you guess correctly will be white.  Is that correcrt?  If so, please edit to clarify the question.  And in any case, edit to include your efforts.

Comment: That is more along the lines of what the question I am intending to ask. Thanks for the feedback, and I will try and edit appropriately

Comment: Note:  for whatever reason, I switched from red to white in my rewritten version.  The color doesn't matter, obviously, but it's meant to be the same color in both cases.

Comment: @JohnDale: After transforming the problem, does only the color (red or non-red) matter, or are all the $5$ reds  to be treated as distinct ?

Comment: all balls are to treated as distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to note that your question is essentially equivalent to applying a random permutation to the colored set $[12] = \{1, 2, \cdots, 12\}$ and asking about the probability that the number of red fixed points exceeds two. Anyway,

$P(\text{Guessing} \geq $2$ \text{ red balls right}) =1 -  P(\text{Guessing} \leq  $1$ \text{ red ball right})$

$P(\text{Guessing} \leq  $1$ \text{ red ball right}) = P(A_0)+P(A_1)+\cdots+ P(A_5) = P(A_0) + 5P(A_1)$

Where $A_0$ is the event that no red ball is guessed right and for $1 \leq i \leq 5$ $A_i$ is the event that the only red ball guessed right is the $i$th one (the $A_i$s are disjoint so the probability of their union is just the sum of their probabilities). Further

$P(A_0) = P(B_1^{c}\cap B_2^{c} \cap \cdots \cap B_{5}^{c})$ where $B_i$ is the event that the $i$th red ball is guessed correctly. So by De Morgans laws

$P(A_0) = 1 - P(B_1\cup B_2\cup \cdots\cup B_5)$

$P(B_1\cup B_2\cup \cdots\cup B_5)$ can be computed using the principle of inclusion and exclusion, because $P(B_{i_1}\cap \cdots \cap B_{i_k}) = \dfrac{(12-k)!}{12!}$. Similarly, one can use PIE to find the value of $P(A_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

$$P(A_1) = P(\text{1st red ball is guessed right})\times P(\text{no other ball is guess right}|\text{1st red ball is guessed right})$$

This is the same as $$\dfrac{1}{12}\times P(B_2^{c}\cap B_3^{c} \cap B_4^{c} \cap B_5^{c}|B_1) =\dfrac{1}{12}(1 - P(B_2\cup B_3\cup B_4 \cup B_5|B_1))$$

Now you can apply PIE again. Some calculation suggests that the answer is $\approx 6.18$%

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was posted before the question was edited to replace "Domino pizzas" with "numbered red balls".*

The problem is phrased a bit ambiguously, but I can only find one way to interpret it that leads to a definite answer.

Let me rephrase my interpretation of the problem:

> There are 12 pizzas, 5 of which are Domino pizzas, and the other 7 are not-Domino pizzas. The pizzas are arranged in a row in a permutation chosen uniformly at random.
>
> A blindfolded person randomly attributes each pizza a label, "Domino" or "not-Domino", so that in total, 5 pizzas are labeled "Domino" and 7 pizzas are labeled "not-Domino". What is the probability that at least 2 Domino pizzas are labeled "Domino"?

#### Method 1

"At least two Domino pizzas are labeled Domino" is the exact negation of "All Domino pizzas are labeled not-Domino, or exactly 1 Domino pizza is labeled Domino and the other 4 are labeled not-Domino".

The probability that all domino pizzas are labeled not-Domino is $\frac{7}{12}\times\frac{6}{11}\times\frac{5}{10}\times\frac{4}{9}\times\frac{3}{8} = \frac{21}{792} \approx 2.65\%$.

The probability that exactly 1 Domino pizza is labeled Domino is $5 \times \frac{5}{12}\times\frac{7}{11}\times\frac{6}{10}\times\frac{5}{9}\times\frac{4}{8} = \frac{175}{792} \approx 22.10\%$.

These two events are mutually exclusive, so the probability that neither of them happens is exactly 100% minus their sum: Finally the probability that at least two Domino pizzas are labeled correctly is $1 - (\frac{21}{792} + \frac{175}{792}) = \frac{792 - 21 - 175}{792} = \frac{596}{792} \approx 75.25\%$.

#### Method 2

The number of distinct ways to label all twelve pizzas is equal to $\binom{12}{5}=\frac{12\times 11\times 10\times 9\times 8}{5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1} = 792$, since it is equivalent to choosing which 5 pizzas to label "Domino" among the 12 pizzas.

For $k=2,3,4,5$, the number of distinct ways to label all twelve pizzas so that exactly $k$ of them are labeled "Domino" is $\binom{5}{k}\times\binom{7}{5-k}$. For instance if $k=2$, this corresponds to choosing which 2 Domino pizzas to correctly label "Domino" among the 5 Domino pizzas, and which 3 non-Domino pizzas to label "Domino" among the 7 non-Domino pizzas.

The four events corresponding to $k=2,3,4,5$ are mutually exclusive, so the total number of distinct ways to label all twelve pizzas so that at least $k$ of them are labeled "Domino" is the sum: $\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{7}{3}+\binom{5}{3}\times\binom{7}{2}+\binom{5}{4}\times\binom{7}{1}+\binom{5}{5}\times\binom{7}{0} = 596$.

Since all those distinct ways to label the 12 pizzas are equiprobable, the probability of correctly labeling at least 2 of the 5 Domino pizzas is the quotient $\frac{596}{792} \approx 75.25\%$